# Javascript get month range by month name

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, range

I have a jQuery onclick function which basically receives a month name, and from that month name, I would like to get a month range. Like for instance I'm passing a month name "May" like this:

```
 $('#swiperNext').click(function(e)
   {
       var currentMonth = $('.swiper-slide-active h3').html();
       console.log(currentMonth);
   });
```

Now I'd like to pass the current month name to a JS function and get date range for that month.

So for example May would be => 01-05-2016 - 31-05-2016, so on and so on... Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without any third party library like this.

I presume you are calculation for current year

```
var date = new Date();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var month = $('.swiper-slide-active h3').text();
var m = new Date(Date.parse(month, 1, " + y)).getMonth();

var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
```

EDIT: I have changed the answer to use a month name as a string

Comment: instead of yourMonth I'll pass the variable that I already have, which is supposed to be a string "May" or "June" ?

Comment: My month variable is basically a string name like "May" ,,, When I pass it I'm getting invalid date error ....

Comment: @AlesMaticic Provide demo to see result.

Comment: @Mohammad have edited the answer and amended the error

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/). It is perfect for manipulating dates and do all sorts of things.

In your specific case:

```
var startOfMonth = moment().month("June").startOf("month").toDate()
var endOfMonth   = moment().month("June").endOf("month").toDate()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to call moment() function like this: ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Comment: you have to include moment to use it

Comment: Can you include in the answer on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
function getMonthFromString(monthName){
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(monthName + 1, new Date().getFullYear()));
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getDate();
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    var month = new Date(Date.parse(monthName + 1, new Date().getFullYear())).getMonth()+1;
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();

       return firstDay + "-" + month + "-" + year + " - " + lastDay + "-" + month + "-" + year;
}
```

Comment: You can use variable monthName  as: Jun, May, Jul, Sep, Nov,... using full or 3 first letters is also work fine :)

Comment: Padding is necessary too

Answer (score 0):

First I create month name array according as getMonth() index.Then find wanted month name by indexOf ,that will return your array index when found it.

> Note getMonth() is only return number between 0 and 11 assume Jan to Dec

So added 1 in getMonth

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
$('#swiperNext').click(function(e)
   {
       var currentMonth = $('.swiper-slide-active h3').html();
       var month = monthNames.indexOf(currentMonth);
       var d = new Date();
       var start = new Date(d.getFullYear(),month,1);
       var end = new Date(d.getFullYear(),month+1,0);
       var startdate = start.getDate()+"/"+(start.getMonth()+1)+"/"+start.getFullYear();
       var enddate = end.getDate()+"/"+(end.getMonth()+1)+"/"+end.getFullYear();
    console.log(startdate+"-"+enddate);
   });
```

Comment: You are not padding